# Loop CSV data from multiple rows in PHP

Tags: php, loops, csv

I'm pretty new to PHP and am really learning as I do, no doubt wrongly at times. I've put together a script that reads a CSV containing orders for an e-commerce site and uses the data to send a completion email to the customer.

My problem is that if a customer orders several items in one order they are sent an email for each of those items rather than all the order items with the same order ID being contained in one email.

Its taken me several hours to to get to this point as I've literally been learning as I go but try as I might I'm banging my head against a brick wall with this loop issue and how to go about it. Any help, guidance or direction pointing would be much appreciated!

```
///////////// RUN THE CSV IMPORT ////////////
if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
    file_put_contents($debug, $date.$m5.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    exit;
}
$file = fopen($csvfile,"r");
if(!$file) {
    file_put_contents($debug, $date.$m6.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    exit;
}
$size = filesize($csvfile);
if(!$size) {
    file_put_contents($debug, $date.$m7.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    exit;
}
$csvcontent = fread($file,$size);
fclose($file);
$lines = 0;
$queries = "";
$linearray = array();
foreach(explode($lineseparator,$csvcontent) as $line) {
    if($lines == 0){ $lines++; continue; }
    if (empty($line)) { break; }
    $lines++;
    $line = trim($line," \t");
    $line = str_replace("\r","",$line);
    $line = str_replace("\"","",$line);
    $linearray = explode($fieldseparator,$line);
    $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);
    // Set The Variables
    $order_id = $linearray[0];
    $order_total = $linearray[1];
    $payment_method = $linearray[2];
    $shipping_cost = $linearray[3];
    $total_quantity = $linearray[6];
    $billing_first_name = $linearray[6];
    $billing_last_name = $linearray[7];
    $billing_company = $linearray[8];
    $billing_street1 = $linearray[9];
    $billing_street2 = $linearray[10];
    $billing_city = $linearray[11];
    $billing_zip = $linearray[12];
    $billing_state = $linearray[13];
    $billing_country = $linearray[14];
    $billing_phone = $linearray[15];
    $billing_email = $linearray[16];
    $shipping_first_name = $linearray[17];
    $shipping_last_name = $linearray[18];
    $shipping_company = $linearray[19];
    $shipping_street1 = $linearray[20];
    $shipping_street2 = $linearray[21];
    $shipping_city = $linearray[22];
    $shipping_zip = $linearray[23];
    $shipping_state = $linearray[24];
    $shipping_country = $linearray[25];
    $sku = $linearray[26];
    $product_name = $linearray[27];
    $order_line_quantity = $linearray[28];
    $order_line_total_price = $linearray[29];
    $ship_provider = $linearray[31];
    $ship_tracking = $linearray[32];
    $order_status = 'wc-completed';
    $ship_date = date("Y-m-d");
    $ship_sent = "on";
    // Use MySQLi for regular price
    $mysqli = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
    }
    $price_id = $mysqli->query("SELECT `post_id` FROM `dk_postmeta` WHERE `meta_value` LIKE '$sku'")->fetch_row()[0];
    $regular_price = $mysqli->query("SELECT `meta_value` FROM `dk_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` =$price_id AND `meta_key` LIKE '_regular_price'")->fetch_row()[0];
    // CLOSE CONNECTION
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    $message = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>'.
        '<head>'.
        '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html">'.
        '<meta charset="UTF-8">'.
        '<title>mysite order complete</title>'.
        '<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">'.
        '<style>
body{font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-weight: 400;font-size:16px;line-height:26px;color:#212121;}
a {color: #7E1414;text-decoration: none;outline: 0px none !important;}
.clear{clear:both;}
.wrapper {margin:0 auto;}
.header {background-color: #151515;color: #FFF;width: auto;height: 70px;border: 1px solid #3C3C3C;padding:0 15px;margin-bottom:20px;}
a.logo {font-size: 38px;color: #FFF;line-height: 38px;letter-spacing: 1px;padding: 15px 0px 0px;}
.logo {float: left;}
.logo-small {font-family: Open Sans;text-transform: uppercase;font-size: 12px;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
.alert {font-size: 30px;color: #FFF;line-height: 38px;letter-spacing: 1px;padding: 15px 0px 0px;float:right}
.container {width:100%;padding:0}
.inner {margin:0 auto; height:100%;}
.my-account h2 {font-size: 22px;line-height: 30px;border-bottom: 1px solid #ABABAB;padding-bottom: 10px;margin: 0px 0px 20px;font-weight:normal;}
.order-box {padding:10px 20px;border:1px solid #ababab;}
.row {border-bottom:1px solid #E3E3E3;padding:10px 0;}
.row-totals {padding:10px 0 2px;}
.red{color:#7E1414;}
.product{width:48%;float:left;}
.product img {max-width:90px;}
.product .img-box{float:left;max-width:90px;border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;border-radius:3px;}
.product p {float:left;padding:0 0 0 10px;margin:0}
.price{width:20%;float:left;}
.quantity{width:10%;float:left;text-align:right;}
.total{width:20%;float:right;text-align:right;}
.totals-box {margin-top:0px;float:right;width:48%}
.totals-inner {padding:10px 20px 15px;border:1px solid #ababab;margin:20px 0;}
.alert-inner,.customer-inner {padding:0 20px;border:1px solid #ababab;margin:0 0 20px;}
.sub-left{float:left;width:40%;color:#7E1414;}
.sub-right{float:right;width:40%;text-align:right;}
.customer-inner {padding:10px 20px 0;margin:0px;}
.black {color:#212121 !important;}
.billing-box {}
.bbox-left {width:48%;float:left;}
.bbox-right {width:48%;float:right;}
.bbox-right .totals-inner,.bbox-left .totals-inner{padding:10px 20px}
.billing-box h3 {font-size: 18px;line-height: 30px;border-bottom: 1px solid #ABABAB;padding-bottom: 10px;margin: 0px 0px 20px;font-weight:normal;}
.billing-box p {padding:0;margin:0;}
.footer{background-color: #151515;color: #FFF;width: auto;border: 1px solid #3C3C3C;padding:0 15px;margin-bottom:0px;}
.footer p {font-size:20px;line-height:30px;padding:0;text-align:center;}
</style>'.
        '</head>'.
        '<body>'.
        '<div class="wrapper">'.
        '<div class="header">'.
        '<div class="logo">'.
        '<a class="logo" href="https://example.com">mysite <span class="logo-small">small logo</span></a>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="alert">'.
        'Order Shipped'.
        '</div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="container">'. 
        '<div class="inner">'.
        '<div class="alert-inner">'.
        '<p>Dear '.$billing_first_name.','.
        '<p>We just wanted to let you know that your recent order with mysite has been completed and shipped on '.$ship_date.'. You can track your order at the <a href="#">EMS website</a> by using their tracking facility and your tracking number '.$ship_tracking.'.</p>'.
        '<p>For your reference your order details are below. Thank you for shopping with mysite!</p>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="my-account">'.
        '<div class="order-box">'.
        '<h2>Order Details</h2>'.
        '<div class="row red">'.
        '<div class="product">Product</div>'.
        '<div class="price">Price</div>'.
        '<div class="quantity">Quantity</div>'.
        '<div class="total">Total</div>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '</div>'.
        // NEED TO LOOP THIS SECTION WITH DATA FROM OTHER ROWS THAT MATCH $order_id 
        '<div class="row">'.
        '<div class="product">'.
        '<div class="img-box">'.
        '<img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/'.$sku.'-1-135x180.jpg">'.
        '</div>'.
        '<p class="item">'.$product_name.'</p>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="price">USD '.$regular_price.'</div>'.
        '<div class="quantity">'.$order_line_quantity.'</div>'.
        '<div class="total">USD '.$order_line_total_price.'</div>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '</div>'.
        // END THE LOOP
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="totals-box">'.
        '<div class="totals-inner">'.
        '<div class="row row-totals">'.
        '<div class="sub-left">SubTotal</div>'.
        '<div class="sub-right">USD '.$order_line_total_price.'</div>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="row row-totals">'.
        '<div class="sub-left">Shipping</div>'.
        '<div class="sub-right">USD '.$shipping_cost.'</div>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="row row-totals">'.
        '<div class="sub-left">Payment Method</div>'.
        '<div class="sub-right">'.$payment_method.'</div>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="row row-totals">'.
        '<div class="sub-left">Total</div>'.
        '<div class="sub-right">USD '.$order_total.'</div>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '<div class="customer-inner">'.
        '<h2>Customer details</h2>'.
        '<p><spcan class="black">Telephone:</span> '.$billing_phone.'</p>'.
        '<p>Email: '.$billing_email.'</p>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="billing-box">'.
        '<div class="bbox-left">'.
        '<div class="totals-inner">'.
        '<h3>Billing Details</h3>'.
        '<p>'.$billing_first_name.' '.$billing_last_name.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$billing_company.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$billing_street1.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$billing_street2.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$billing_city.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$billing_zip.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$billing_state.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$billing_country.'</p>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="bbox-right">'.
        '<div class="totals-inner">'.
        '<h3>Shipping Details</h3>'.
        '<p>'.$shipping_first_name.' '.$shipping_last_name.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$shipping_company.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$shipping_street1.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$shipping_street2.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$shipping_city.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$shipping_zip.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$shipping_state.'</p>'.
        '<p>'.$shipping_country.'</p>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="clear"></div>'.
        '</div>'.  
        '</div>'.
        '<div class="footer">'.
        '<p>Thank you for your custom!</p>'.
        '</div>'.
        '</div>'.
        '</body>';
    /*EMAIL TEMPLATE ENDS*/
    $to      = $billing_email;             // give to email address
    $subject = 'Your Order Is Complete';  //change subject of email
    $from    = 'orders@example.com';                           // give from email address
    $headers  = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "CC: \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8\r\n";
    // Sending mail
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo 'HTML email sent successfully!';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Problem sending HTML email!';
    }
```

Comment: If you want to read, parse and write CSV data, have a look at [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) which should ease your workflow a lot.